# Pandas GroupBy to calculate weighted percentages meeting a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with survey data like so, with each row being a different respondent.

```
weight    race      Question_1      Question_2      Question_3
   0.9   white               1               5               4
   1.1   asian               5               4               3
  0.95   white               2               1               5
  1.25   black               5               4               3
  0.80   other               4               5               2
```

Each question is on a scale from 1 to 5 (there are several more questions in the actual data). For each question, I am trying to calculate the percentage of respondents who responded with a 5, grouped by race and weighted by the weight column.

I believe that the code below works for calculating the percentage who responded with a 5 for each question, grouped by race. But I do not know how to weight it by the weight column.

```
df.groupby('race').apply(lambda x: ((x == 5).sum()) / x.count())
```

I am new to pandas. Could someone please explain how to do this? Thanks for any help.

Edit: The desired output for the above dataframe would look something like this. Obviously the real data has far more respondents (rows) and many more questions.

```
        Question_1      Question_2      Question_3
white         0.00            0.49            0.51
black         1.00            0.00            0.00
asian         1.00            0.00            0.00
other         0.00            1.00            0.00
```

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose I don't understand. I made those percentages up to illustrate the type of output I am looking for.

Comment: I have edited what the desired output for the above dataframe would be. Of course the real data has far more rows and many more questions. Thank you.

Comment: You say that you want to use the weight column, but your desired output does not reflect that. Do you want the weight to be in the calculation?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have edited to account for weights. I definitely want weights in the calculation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution by defining a custom function and applying that function to each columns. Then you could concatenate each column into a dataframe:

```
def wavg(x, col):
    return (x['weight']*(x[col]==5)).sum()/x['weight'].sum()

grouped = df.groupby('race')
pd.concat([grouped.apply(wavg,col) for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Question')],axis=1)\
    .rename(columns = {num:f'Question_{num+1}' for num in range(3)})
```

Output:

```
        Question_1  Question_2  Question_3
race            
asian   1.0         0.000000    0.000000
black   1.0         0.000000    0.000000
other   0.0         1.000000    0.000000
white   0.0         0.486486    0.513514
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Joe. Really helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it for question 1. You can easily generalize it for the other questions.

```
# Define a dummy indicating a '5 response'
df['Q1'] = np.where(df['Question_1']==5 ,1, 0)

# Create a weighted version of the above dummy
df['Q1_w'] = df['Q1'] * df['weight']

# Compute the sum by race
ds = df.groupby(['race'])[['Q1_w', 'weight']].sum()

# Compute the weighted average
ds['avg'] = ds['Q1_w'] / ds['weight']
```

Basically, you first take the sum of the weights and of the weighted `5 dummy` by race and then divide by the sum of the weights.
This gives you the weighted average.